# How to pass kwargs to argparse

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse, keyword-argument

I need to pass a dictionary to a python module via a command line.  I have not found a way to get Python to cooperate.  The following is a very simplified example of what I'd like to accomplish.  This produces the following error `TypeError: _get_positional_kwargs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dest'`
. Adding a `dest` argument to the add_argument line results in `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'`, indicating the sad possibility that argparse simply may not take a dictionary as an argument.  Is a pickle file truly the only option for passing dictionaries back and forth from command line calls?

```
def run(**kwargs):
for i in kwargs.items():
    print(f'{i}: {kwargs[i]}')
# ...some code to manipulate the dictionary
return kwargs


if __name__ == "__main__":
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Test script")
parser.add_argument(kwargs='**', description='A dictionary to be manipulated and returned')
args = parser.parse_args()
x = run(args)
pass
```

**Additional info** - I know that I can pass a list to a `*nargs` argument with a command line that includes space-delimited arguments, but I need to do something similar with a dictionary.

**UPDATE - WHAT WORKED:**
Based on the helpful input from @chepner, I was able to get it to work with the json solution he mentioned in his answer.  On my Windows platform, I did have to remove all spaces from the dictionary string and escape characters are required in the final command line string.

`{\"this\":1,\"is\":2,\"a\":5,\"dictionary\":7}`

Comment: "Adding a `dest` argument to the add_argument line" - I don't see any argument called `dest` in your code. You're trying to pass an argument called `kwargs`, but the caller doesn't have direct access to it. You have to pass `kwargs` like you're doing with `description="thing"`.

Comment: `add_argument()` requires at least one positional argument. What are you trying to achieve, what do you expect the keys and values of the dictionary passed to `run()` to contain?

Comment: Could you add an example command line call of your module, helping us to understand what you want to do?

Comment: A command line arg example might be something like:
`C:\Python37\python.exe test.py -this 1 -is 2 -a 3 -dictionary 4`. 
In a normal scenario, I'd be passing hundreds or even thousands of key-value pairs.  The command line call would be code-generated.

Comment: Passing thousands of arguments may not even be possible, depending on your operating system.

Comment: Your `add_argument` call does not follow documentation.  For arbitrary `key - value` pairs parsing the `sys.argv` is probably easier.  `argparse` is designed to give you the programmer control over the inputs, with a limited number of defined keys/flags.  There are better formats for passing large numbers of values (as string or file) - JSON, yaml, config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are strings, period. What you want to pass is a string that contains an *encoded* `dict`, for example using JSON.

```
import argparse
import json


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('data', type=json.loads)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

If you run your script with something like

```
myscript '{"foo": 3, "bar": "hello"}'
```

then `args.data["foo"] == 3` and `args.data["bar"] == "hello"`.

Comment: The basic idea makes sense, but it does not yet work.  If I pass `'{"this": 1, "is": 2, "a": 3, "dictionary": 4}'` (single-quotes, double-quotes doesn't make a difference) I get an error:  `error: argument data: invalid loads value: '{this:'`

Comment: How *exactly* are you running the script? That's the error I get (when running the script from `bash`) when I use `./myscript.py {"this": 1, "is": 2, "a": 3, "dictionary": 4}`, not `./myscript.py '{"this": 1, "is": 2, "a": 3, "dictionary": 4}'`. (The quotes matter; the JSON itself must use double quotes, and the single quotes prevent the shell from performing wordsplitting and quote removal before `myscript.py` is even called.)

Comment: More briefly: you are somehow passing multiple arguments `{this:`, `1,` `is:`, etc to your script, not a single argument `{"this": 1, "is": 2, ...}`.

Comment: In this case, I'm using PyCharm on a Windows machine, but the error is the same from a command prompt:
`C:\>python "C:\test\test.py" '{"this": "1", "is": "2", "a": "5", "dictionary": "7"}'
usage: test.py [-h] data
test.py: error: argument data: invalid loads value: "'{this:"`

Comment: These are all platform-specific issues with how to provide a single string argument to Python, not related to Python itself.

Comment: I would beg to disagree - I believe the question is quite valid as a python argparse issue. It MIGHT be answered by use of json, as indicated in your original answer; however, I declined to mark it as an answer without getting it to actually work.  I will definitely give it a thumbs up.

Comment: There may be other approaches, but your issue of having the wrong argument received by Python is *entirely* an issue with how you are executing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209950/discussion-between-cnidog-and-chepner).